# Finally block not executed with return and await C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, c#-6.0

I'm using Xamarin Studio 5.9.8 with Xamarin.iOS 9.1.0.27.

I try this code snippet, and surprisingly **method D does not execute** at all.

**Edit** Changed example code to more detailed example.

```
public async Task<bool> TryFinallyTest()
{
    try
    {
        GoToFuture();

        bool future = DateTime.Today.Year > 2020;

        try
        {
            if( !future )
                return false;

            Console.WriteLine("You are in the future!");
        }
        finally
        {
            await BackToPresent();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NOT EXECUTED!");
    }

    return true;
}

private void GoToFuture()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Go to future!");
}

private async Task BackToPresent()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Back to present");
}
```

Obviously, my real code is more complicated than this, this is only a simplification for test purposes.

Really D does not execute?

**Edit** I tested this example in VisualStudio 2015 and works fine. The second finally executes normally. The problem only happens in Xamarin.iOS, i think it's a mono bug or something like that. Thanks.

Comment: just curious ..what does `C()` look like in your test as you put it and what does `D()` look like perhaps you need to consult with the Documentation on `Xamarin` [Async & Await the Difference](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/async-await-c-xamarin-wallace-mcclure)

Comment: How do you call this method

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Note that if you are able to get the code example to work in the regular desktop version of .NET, but not in the context of Xamarin on iOS, then it's most likely a compiler or runtime bug. Regardless, you need to provide enough detail for others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I edit the post with a more detailed example, and tested it on VisualStudio 2015. The prolemn only appears in Xamarin environment. Is a mono touch bug?